# React fetch data and set state accordingly doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect

In the code below the `settings` variable is not being set. I did check with `console.log` after the
`setSettings` and also I verified the component using the variable is receiving the default `{}` value. The fetch *per se* is right, I tried in the browser's console and I see the json in the Network tab.

I need the fetch be done once, at the first rendering.

Could you please take a look? I've spent lots of time on this and I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

```js
    const [settings, setSettings] = React.useState({});

    function fetchSettings() {
        fetch("MYAPIENDPOINT/settings", {
            method: "GET",
            credentials: 'include',
            accept: 'application/json',
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            }
            throw response;
        })
        .then((data) => {
            setSettings(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {console.log(error);});

    }

    React.useEffect(
        fetchSettings(),
        [settings]
    );
```

**EDIT** to show the component using the `settings` variable

```js
    ...
    <div id="Grid" style={{ height: "700px" }}>
        {settings && <GenericGrid settings={settings} />}
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see any overt issue with the `setSettings(data)` call. The only issue I see is using `settings` as the dependency for the `useEffect` hook which updates the `settings` state. This is likely causing a render loop. Where is `settings` being used that you aren't seeing it update?

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for your response. I tried to remove the `settings` dependency but It still errors. I've updated the question to show the component

Comment: Errors?! What are the errors?

Comment: useEffect(() => {
fetchSettings();
}, []) is the right sintax.

useEffect accepts 2 arguments: callback and dependency array

Comment: OMG that's true, shite @OktayYuzcan thanks!!! I'll tick your answer if you write it! Thanks dude!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useEffect accepts 2 arguments: callback and dependency array.

The right syntax is:

```
useEffect(() => {
   function fetchSettings(){
      ...
   }

   fetchSettings();
}, [])
```

If you want the callback to trigger only once, leave the dependency array empty.
Also better define the fetchSettings function inside the callback, so it does not recreate on each render.